# Same ssh key and/or container ID between docker-compose up and down's?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, ssh-keys

How do I maintain the same ssh key and/or container ID across docker-compose up and down's?

I'm doing up and down's frequently and want to keep just one ssh key in my known hosts file.

Below is the error i am getting.

```
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
... yada yada ...
ERROR: Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Can you `exec` into the container? Do you need to recreate the container when using up/down (vs stop/start)? If it's a private network you 100% trust, you can use `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to avoid that ssh error.

Comment: Put code into code blocks. Less words, more specific. Don't bloat the question down with messy garble code.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose down` stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by `docker-compose up`. This leads to the container's identity changes.

AS SSH has no way of knowing whether you've changed the identity or a man-in-the-middle attack is ongoing, it decides to bring this to your attention.

There're several ways to work around this.

**Disable SSH strict key checking**

As @ldg pointed out in the comment, you can use `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxx` to disable the strict key checking. Do not overuse this method, because it can lead to security risks.

**Delete the relevant entry in know_hosts**

Find the relevant entry in file `/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts` and delete it. The error message already gives you a hint: `ERROR: Offending RSA key in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:7`.

**Use `docker attach` instead of SSH**

The `docker attach` command attaches local STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR to the stream. See docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/.